# python float object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, object, variable-assignment

I am running the following code, but I get the error message 'float' object does not support item assignment. My desired output is to append the results of those calculations in the vector Vi

```
import numpy as np

MolWeight = [132, 320, 29, 45, 10]
Ci = 10 # g/L initial Concentration
Cf = 50*10**(-6) #M final Concentration
Vf = 100*10**(-6) #Litre final Volume
Vi = []
for i in range(len(MolWeight)):
    #How many moles of the compounds are there in the standard solution
    Mi = Ci/MolWeight[i] #M
    #this corresponds to the initial concentration of the standard     compound
    Ci = Mi #M/L
    #I calculate the volume to extract from the standard compound    solution, so to obtain the desired concentration 
    np.append.Vi[i] = (Cf*Vf)/Ci #L
```

Comment: @Evert append brace is wrong `Vi[i].append(Cf*Vf/Ci)`. But correct suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

you can just do

```
Vi.append((Cf*Vf)/Ci) #L
```

output:

```
Vi
[6.599999999999998e-08,
 2.1119999999999998e-05,
 0.0006124799999999999,
 0.027561599999999995,
 0.27561599999999997]
```

Answer (score 0):

was this what you were looking for?
I think the problem was int division and in append

```
import numpy as np

MolWeight = [132.0, 320.0, 29.0, 45.0, 10.0]
Ci = 10.0 # g/L initial Concentration
Cf = 50*10**(-6) #M final Concentration
Vf = 100*10**(-6) #Litre final Volume
Vi = []
for i in range(len(MolWeight)):
    #How many moles of the compounds are there in the standard solution
    Mi = Ci/MolWeight[i] #M
    #this corresponds to the initial concentration of the standard     compound
    Ci = Mi  # M/L
    #I calculate the volume to extract from the standard compound    solution, so to obtain the desired concentration 
    # np.append.Vi[i] = (Cf * Vf) / Ci  # L
    Vi.append((Cf * Vf) / Ci )


print Vi
```

output

```
 [6.599999999999998e-08, 2.1119999999999998e-05, 0.0006124799999999999, 0.027561599999999995, 0.27561599999999997]
```